# How to create a blank mp3 using ffmpeg?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk

I have built ffmpeg for android by using android NDK. I am using cocos game-engine to compile and run the project. I want to create a blank mp3 of lets say 20 seconds when a button is pressed. I have tried almost everything. The following command generates an output file but it is of 0 bytes.

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc=r=48000 -t 20 -codec copy /sdcard/output.mp3
```

My ffmpeg configuration is :

```
> ./configure \
>     --prefix=$PREFIX \
>     --disable-network \
>     --disable-doc \
>     --disable-ffplay \
>     --disable-ffprobe \
>     --disable-ffserver \
>     --disable-symver \
>     --cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
>     --target-os=linux \
>     --arch=arm \
>     --enable-cross-compile \
>     --sysroot=$SYSROOT \
>     --extra-cflags="-Os -fpic $ADDI_CFLAGS" \
>     --extra-ldflags="$ADDI_LDFLAGS" \
```

Any help would be appreciated. I am testing this on an android phone. I have built static libraries for ffmpeg and they are linked to the project.

Comment: What would be the sense of creating a mute mp3 file? Pause the player for 20 sec, instead of playing a mute file. It would also help limiting your app's size.

Comment: I am using the blank file later to merge with a video for a particular amount of time. I have already tested the both the parts on a Linux build and they seem to work fine.

Comment: You need a MP3 encoder like libmp3lame included.

Comment: IIRC, libshine may be faster on ARM (although it will likely take hardly any time for libmp3lame to encode 20 seconds of silence).